# Is bitcoin core secure?

Tags: bitcoin-core, security

Amir Taaki says Bitcoin Core is not secure because of undefined behaviour in this video https://youtu.be/EPpDpULPhHc after 30:00

Is this true and how can we fix this? What are the risks of using bitcoin core?

Answer (score 4):

Undefined behavior is considered a bug, and as with all bugs, software developers try to avoid writing these things. However, as with all other software, bugs do slip in. Just because there may be a bug of a particular type does not mean that the software is insecure. Bugs can have a wide variety of effects, ranging from merely annoying (such as the software crashing), to extremely dangerous (such as one that allows for remote code execution).

There are no known bugs in the wallet that would compromise your private keys. There are no known bugs in the software that would allow for an attacker to take over your computer. The vast majority of users and developers consider Bitcoin Core to be secure.